# convert from IPLImage to QImage in Qt

Tags: qt, opencv, qimage, iplimage

I would like to display image in qt window , so I used Qlabel->setpixmap

but how can I convert from IPLImage to QImage to display it in the label??

I found the follwing function to convert it but I did not know how to use it in call statement

```
QImage *IplImageToQImage(const IplImage * iplImage, uchar **data, double mini, double maxi)
{
    uchar *qImageBuffer = NULL;
    int width = iplImage->width;
    int widthStep = iplImage->widthStep;
    int height = iplImage->height;
    switch (iplImage->depth)
    {
        case IPL_DEPTH_8U:
        if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
        {
        // OpenCV image is stored with one byte grey pixel. We convert it
       // to an 8 bit depth QImage.
        //

        qImageBuffer = (uchar *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(uchar));
        uchar *QImagePtr = qImageBuffer;
        const uchar *iplImagePtr = (const uchar *) iplImage->imageData;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Copy line by line
            memcpy(QImagePtr, iplImagePtr, width);
            QImagePtr += width;
            iplImagePtr += widthStep;
        }

        }
        else if (iplImage->nChannels == 3)
        {
            /* OpenCV image is stored with 3 byte color pixels (3 channels).
            We convert it to a 32 bit depth QImage.
            */
            qImageBuffer = (uchar *) malloc(width*height*4*sizeof(uchar));
            uchar *QImagePtr = qImageBuffer;
            const uchar *iplImagePtr = (const uchar *) iplImage->imageData;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // We cannot help but copy manually.
                    QImagePtr[0] = iplImagePtr[0];
                    QImagePtr[1] = iplImagePtr[1];
                    QImagePtr[2] = iplImagePtr[2];
                    QImagePtr[3] = 0;

                    QImagePtr += 4;
                    iplImagePtr += 3;
                }
            iplImagePtr += widthStep-3*width;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=8U and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);
        }
        break;
        case IPL_DEPTH_16U:
        if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
        {
        /* OpenCV image is stored with 2 bytes grey pixel. We convert it
        to an 8 bit depth QImage.
        */
            qImageBuffer = (uchar *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(uchar));
            uchar *QImagePtr = qImageBuffer;
            //const uint16_t *iplImagePtr = (const uint16_t *);
            const unsigned int *iplImagePtr = (const unsigned int *)iplImage->imageData;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                // We take only the highest part of the 16 bit value. It is
                //similar to dividing by 256.
                *QImagePtr++ = ((*iplImagePtr++) >> 8);
                }
                iplImagePtr += widthStep/sizeof(unsigned int)-width;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=16U and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);

        }
        break;
        case IPL_DEPTH_32F:
         if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
         {
        /* OpenCV image is stored with float (4 bytes) grey pixel. We
        convert it to an 8 bit depth QImage.
        */
             qImageBuffer = (uchar *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(uchar));
             uchar *QImagePtr = qImageBuffer;
             const float *iplImagePtr = (const float *) iplImage->imageData;
             for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
             {
                 for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                 {
                     uchar p;
                     float pf = 255 * ((*iplImagePtr++) - mini) / (maxi - mini);
                     if (pf < 0) p = 0;
                     else if (pf > 255) p = 255;
                     else p = (uchar) pf;

                     *QImagePtr++ = p;
                  }
             iplImagePtr += widthStep/sizeof(float)-width;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=32F and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);
         }
       break;
       case IPL_DEPTH_64F:
         if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
         {
            /* OpenCV image is stored with double (8 bytes) grey pixel. We
            convert it to an 8 bit depth QImage.
            */
            qImageBuffer = (uchar *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(uchar));
            uchar *QImagePtr = qImageBuffer;
            const double *iplImagePtr = (const double *) iplImage->imageData;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    uchar p;
                    double pf = 255 * ((*iplImagePtr++) - mini) / (maxi - mini);

                    if (pf < 0) p = 0;
                    else if (pf > 255) p = 255;
                    else p = (uchar) pf;

                    *QImagePtr++ = p;
                }
}

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=64F and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);
        }
        break;
        default:
        qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=%d and %d channels\n", iplImage->depth, iplImage->nChannels);
    }
    QImage *qImage;
    QVector<QRgb> vcolorTable;
    if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
    {
        // We should check who is going to destroy this allocation.
        QRgb *colorTable = new QRgb[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
           colorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i);
           vcolorTable[i] = colorTable[i];
        }
        qImage = new QImage(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        qImage->setColorTable(vcolorTable);
    }
    else
    {
        qImage = new QImage(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    }
    *data = qImageBuffer;
    return qImage;
}
```

The parameter was:
const IplImage * iplImage, uchar **data, double mini, double maxi

what are data,mini,max? how can I get it from my IPLImage to use it in call statement?

Thanks alot :)

Comment: I just found an error in the code !! IPL_DEPTH_16U "const unsigned int" should be changed there with "const unsigned short"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `data` is not used by the code, and `mini` and `maxi` are used for converting floating point values that certain image formats use to integer values in the range 0-255.

I'd try using NULL for data. `mini` and `maxi` really depend on the image data, and I don't know what reasonable ranges are. But if your IplImage is not stored as floating point values then these values shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: sorry I coped incomplete code, it used in *data = qImage Buffer; where can I get it? and is the returened qimage is acceptable in setpixmap? thank you.

Comment: The code calls `qImage = new QImage(qImageBuffer...` and returns qImageBuffer in `data`. If you're not interested, you can just remove that line and remove the parameter from the function. As for whether it works or not - I suggest you try. I'm afraid I've never used OpenCV.

Comment: I tried it with omitted line as you said , there is run time error: Microsoft visual C++ Runtime Library.This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. if I write ui->label->setpixmap(Qpixmap::fromImage(qimg)) the error msg appear:no matching function for call to Qpixmap::fromImage(QImage*&),how can solve these problems.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a QImage where the data is owned by something else (eg the IPLImage) using the QImage(data,widht,height,format) and data is the IPLImage data ptr as long as the format isthe samein both QImage and IPLImage (eg RGB888 = 8U_C3)

Answer (score 0):

I have found some bugs in the code.... maybe there are still more bugs in it but for now it looks fine for me. QImage with Format_Index8 needs sometimes (depending on the image resolution....) 2 byte added on the right side (don t know why but it seems like to be like this).
Here is the new adapted code

```
QImage *IplImageToQImage(const IplImage * iplImage, uchar **data, double mini, double maxi)
{
    uchar *qImageBuffer = NULL;
    int width = iplImage->width;
    int widthStep = iplImage->widthStep;
    int height = iplImage->height;
    QImage *qImage;
    switch (iplImage->depth)
    {
        case IPL_DEPTH_8U:
        if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
        {
        // OpenCV image is stored with one byte grey pixel. We convert it
       // to an 8 bit depth QImage.
        qImage = new QImage(width,height,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        uchar *QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(0);
        qImageBuffer = qImage->scanLine(0);

        const uchar *iplImagePtr = (const uchar *) iplImage->imageData;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Copy line by line
            QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(y);            
            memcpy(QImagePtr, iplImagePtr, width);
            iplImagePtr += widthStep;

        }
        /*
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                // We take only the highest part of the 16 bit value. It is
                //similar to dividing by 256.
                //*QImagePtr++ = ((*iplImagePtr++) >> 8);
                *QImagePtr = *iplImagePtr;
                QImagePtr++;
                iplImagePtr++;
                }

                iplImagePtr += widthStep/sizeof(uchar)-width;
            }*/
        }
        else if (iplImage->nChannels == 3)
            {
            /* OpenCV image is stored with 3 byte color pixels (3 channels).
            We convert it to a 32 bit depth QImage.
            */
            qImageBuffer = (uchar *) malloc(width*height*4*sizeof(uchar));
            uchar *QImagePtr = qImageBuffer;
            const uchar *iplImagePtr = (const uchar *) iplImage->imageData;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // We cannot help but copy manually.
                    QImagePtr[0] = iplImagePtr[0];
                    QImagePtr[1] = iplImagePtr[1];
                    QImagePtr[2] = iplImagePtr[2];
                    QImagePtr[3] = 0;

                    QImagePtr += 4;
                    iplImagePtr += 3;
                }
            iplImagePtr += widthStep-3*width;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=8U and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);
        }
        break;
        case IPL_DEPTH_16U:
        if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
        {
        /* OpenCV image is stored with 2 bytes grey pixel. We convert it
        to an 8 bit depth QImage.
        */
            qImage = new QImage(width,height,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
            uchar *QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(0);
            qImageBuffer = qImage->scanLine(0);

            //const uint16_t *iplImagePtr = (const uint16_t *);
            const unsigned short *iplImagePtr = (const unsigned short *)iplImage->imageData;


            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                // We take only the highest part of the 16 bit value. It is
                //similar to dividing by 256.
                //*QImagePtr++ = ((*iplImagePtr++) >> 8);
                //change here 16 bit could be everything !! set max min to your desire
                *QImagePtr = 255*(((*iplImagePtr) - mini) / (maxi - mini));
                QImagePtr++;
                iplImagePtr++;
                }

                iplImagePtr += widthStep/sizeof(unsigned short)-width;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=16U and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);

        }
        break;
        case IPL_DEPTH_32F:
         if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
         {
        /* OpenCV image is stored with float (4 bytes) grey pixel. We
        convert it to an 8 bit depth QImage.
        */
             qImage = new QImage(width,height,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
             uchar *QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(0);
             qImageBuffer = qImage->scanLine(0);

             const float *iplImagePtr = (const float *) iplImage->imageData;
             for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
             {
             QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(y);
                 for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                 {
                     uchar p;
                     float pf = 255 * ((*iplImagePtr++) - mini) / (maxi - mini);
                     if (pf < 0) p = 0;
                     else if (pf > 255) p = 255;
                     else p = (uchar) pf;

                     *QImagePtr++ = p;
                  }

             iplImagePtr += widthStep/sizeof(float)-width;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=32F and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);
         }
       break;
       case IPL_DEPTH_64F:
         if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
         {
            /* OpenCV image is stored with double (8 bytes) grey pixel. We
            convert it to an 8 bit depth QImage.
            */
             qImage = new QImage(width,height,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
             uchar *QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(0);
             qImageBuffer = qImage->scanLine(0);

            const double *iplImagePtr = (const double *) iplImage->imageData;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
             QImagePtr = qImage->scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    uchar p;
                    double pf = 255 * ((*iplImagePtr++) - mini) / (maxi - mini);

                    if (pf < 0) p = 0;
                    else if (pf > 255) p = 255;
                    else p = (uchar) pf;

                    *QImagePtr++ = p;
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=64F and %d channels\n", iplImage->nChannels);
        }
        break;
        default:
        qDebug("IplImageToQImage: image format is not supported : depth=%d and %d channels\n", iplImage->depth, iplImage->nChannels);
    }

    QVector<QRgb> vcolorTable;
    if (iplImage->nChannels == 1)
    {
        // We should check who is going to destroy this allocation.
        vcolorTable.resize(256);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
           vcolorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i);
        }
        //Qt vector is difficult to use... start with std to qvector
        //here I allocate QImage using qt constructor (Forma_Indexed8 adds sometimes 2 bytes on the right side !!! o.O not specified nowhere !!!)
        //qImage = new QImage(tmpImg->scanLine(0), width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        qImage->setColorTable(vcolorTable);
    }
    else
    {
        qImage = new QImage(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    }
    *data = qImageBuffer;
    return qImage;
}
```

I don t know if 3 channels have also the same bug but I hope not